# Is there a better way other than setting data class constructor values to null if its possible the data cannot be set

Tags: null, kotlin, data-class

I have a situation whereby I am creating a rest client in kotlin as a practical learning exercise and have recently come up against this:

```
             data class ai constructor(val statusCode: Int,
                                       val a: Long? = null,
                                       val b: Long? = null,
                                       val c: Date? = null,
                                       val d: Long? = null,
                                       val e: String? = null,
                                       val f: String? = null)
```

The issue is this, if I get a 200 returned i will have the data to populate 'a' through 'f' but if instead i get a 401 or pretty much any other status code i will not have the data to populate 'a' through 'f' and therefore i have opted for the above solution where I only force the status code which i will always get back to not be null and then defaulted every other value to null.

I don't want to go down the route of setting defaults to things like "" or -1 because then there is always the chance that this data will somehow get through if a user does not check the status code.

Really i want to convey that the information is not present, it seems like this would do that but I wondered if there is a better way.

Comment: You could always have another class `Something` to hold the `Long, Long, Date, Long, String, String`, and then store a `Something?` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) for this:

```
sealed class Result

data class Success constructor(val statusCode: Int = 200,
                               val a: Long,
                               val b: Long,
                               val c: Date,
                               val d: Long,
                               val e: String,
                               val f: String): Result()

data class Failure(val statusCode: Int): Result()
```

(I don't know if the explicit constructor for your class was intentional, if there are annotations on it, etc.)

This way if you have a successful call, you'll create a `Success` instance, and if you have a failed call, you can create a `Failure` instance which doesn't even contain the properties representing the data received (come to think of it, you could move `statusCode` to the `Result` class, that's another choice to make).

Here's how you could then handle these results:

```
fun processResult(result: Result) {
    when (result) {
        is Success -> { /* Use result, which is smart cast to a Success now */ }
        is Failure -> { /* Use result, which is smart cast to a Failure now */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: may i ask what you mean by explicit constructor, is there an implicit form of the above ?

Comment: Compare the way `Success` and `Failure` have their constructors implemented. One of them has the `constructor` keyword explicitly written down, while the other omits it. You only need the keyword there if you need to annotate the constructor (for example, for dependency injection).